# How to use localStorage without any security issues?

Tags: angular, jwt, local-storage, token

How can we store the tokens in the localStorage so that we can maintain the session?

I have checked that there is a possiblity to modify the localStorage in the browser.

Is it ok to store the ID of the user and the name of the user in the localStorage?

It is modifiable in the browser. So what is the best way to store the user info so that it can be user in the front end?

For Example,

The id of the user is modifiable in the localStorage which will cause a serious security issue.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't. Keep in mind that the front-end is never really secure (although you should follow some guidelines to limit security issues).

It is your backend which will be in charge of the security. For example when you receive a PUT request on the user entity, you must check :
- that the user you are getting from the token is the user being modified
- or that the user (from the token) has the permission to modify users.

I will point out that usually cookies are more secured than local/session storage: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage.